# Porque é que a conta comunidade aparece como editor?

Tags: debate, edição

A conta comunidade aparece como editora em algumas perguntas. Mas porque?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso seja necessário estas sao as perguntas da imagem:

[Checkbox selecionada javascript para controller](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49387)

[Definir valor para um cookie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81289)

[Rodapé não aparece na primeira página - Laravel DomPDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126981)

Comment: Isso aí é para dar uma "levantada" na pergunta e ela ficar na lista de "ativos"